# Increase the size of an Android App (.APK)

Tags: android, file, size, apk

I have the problem that I need to reach a certain size of my .apk
Regularly, it is about 2 MBs big which is by far not enough for me.
I want it to climb on 50 MB at least - my first attempt was to revert it into the project files with the apktool and then bomb the project folder with files (pictures, music, etc) to fill 50 MB.

Unfortunately, it did not effect anything - the size stays the same.

How can I increase the size of my app without influencing its functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit the byte code to have a lot of no-ops in it.

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to this - could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: This is a very odd request and my solution requires a deeper understanding of Android than I possess, but somehow it must be possible to access the compiled version of your code. Append 48 MB worth of no-ops to the end of the file. There's a table here that mentions a no-op is 0x10: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html

Comment: I guess if you really wanted you could add a bunch of libraries that - if you don't use them it won't affect the functionality, but it will increase the size of the apk. I'm still at a loss for why you would want to do this however

Answer (score 0):

Add some mp3s or wavs to the project.

Comment: Tried that as well but it also failed.

Answer (score 0):

Add lots of PNG files to your project's res/drawable-mdpi folder.  The build clean and rebuild.

Update - make sure you deploy it to a test device first to insure that the new APK file actually gets generated and can be found in in the project's bin directory.